# Todo application "_underscore.js _.without" in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am having a hard time understanding how the remaining function works in the code below.

(Annotated source: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html)

My understanding of *apply* is the first argument is the context and rest of the arguments is an array to pass as arguments to the function that is being applied.

```
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("todos-backbone"),
    done: function()
    {
        return this.filter(function(todo) { return todo.get('done'); });
    },
    remaining: function()
    {
        return this.without.apply(this, this.done());
    },
});
```

Therefore:

this.without.apply(this, this.done()); --> translates to:

```
without(array of arguments as parameters to without function);
```

*without* takes the first argument as an array and 2...n arguments that you want to remove from the array.

I am not understanding how this function is doing anything useful. What is the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

> this.without.apply(this, this.done()); --> translates to: `without(array);`

Not really. The underscore functions you know as taking the array for the first argument can be applied as methods *on* the backbone collection (like an underscore chaining wrapper). Let's assume that `this.done()` evaluates to `[x, y, z]`, then the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) invocation translates to

```
this.without(x, y, z);
```

Of course, a much more performant method would be to do just

```
return this.filter(function(todo) { return ! todo.get('done'); });
//                                         ^
```

Comment: But if this.done() returns an array, I am still not understanding how it filters out items that are NOT done. I understand your example of this.filter, but there is a piece I must be missing.

Are you saying that this.without.apply is an underscore method that applies something like: this.without(current_collection, array_of_elements_that_are_done?)

Comment: `apply` is not an underscore method, but a native method of Function objects - see the docs I've linked above.

Comment: The way I understand apply is as follows: the first argument is the context of this and the second argument is an array that contains 1...n arguments for the function object. return this.without.apply(this, this.done()) doesn't seem to make sense because this.done() returns an array of objects that are done. I don't see how it filters out items that are not done

Comment: Yes, that's right. And now, the whole collection (`this`) minus (`without`) those that are `done()` are the `remaining` ones (not done)…

Comment: Ah, got it. So "this" is the collection, I think that is what confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone collections have bound method versions of [a bunch of Underscore functions](https://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods), so that

```js
aCollection.filter(iteratee)
```

is (roughly) equivalent to

```js
_.filter(aCollection.models, iteratee)
```

and

```js
aCollection.without(model1, model2, model3, ...)
```

is (roughly) equivalent to

```js
_.without(aCollection.models, model1, model2, model3, ...)
```

among many others. I write "roughly", because the bound method versions [meddle](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7af28186411755cd6c12d6cc716142fb1aeff0b0/backbone.js#L1495-L1507) with the way [iteratee shorthands](https://underscorejs.org/#iteratee) are interpreted, at least nowadays.

Anyway. The `done` method returns an array of models for which the `done` attribute is truthy. The `without` method inverts this set; it returns an array of models for which the `done` attribute is falsy.